# How to define multiple list for autocomplete using codemirror?

Tags: codemirror

I make my own language and using codemirror editor , In my language all class and his methodes defined , so the user only can use class , he can't define a new class ...

For example :

Class A have methods (do1,do2,do3)

Class B have methods (any,click)

I knew how to add all keywords for my language to list and do autocomplete on it using codemirror  ...

My question is :

For example : 
I want when the user type A then type "." Display list only have the methods contain in class A (do1,do2, do3) I don't want to display keywords or methods of class B within the list of class A ... 
So how I can do it with codemirror?

EDIT : 
This is my try   [my example](http://jsbin.com/rozicisepo/edit?html,js,output) but it does not work when I type (ctrl-space) or type (.) Then the same list is appare I want to display a different list deepened on what I type

[my example](http://jsbin.com/rozicisepo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: any body can help me ? Plz

Comment: @Marijn can help me ?